# Java 8 time classes in Cucumber

Tags: java, cucumber

I've got a cucumber datatable representing an object. Some of the fields need to be Instants, some need to be LocalDates. I was looking around and all the posts about parsing java 8 time objects seem to be from a few years ago and I was wondering if there's a library out there that can handle this for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may first want to consider if you need to express the exact dates as part of your scenario. [If the dates are merely incidental to the scenario you should strongly consider removing them from the feature file.](https://cucumber.io/blog/keep-your-scenarios-brief/)

But if you must: jackson-databind is the way to go. It is primarily made to (de)serialize POJO's to and from JSON. As Cucumbers data table can be expressed as a list of json maps we can leverage it.

For this explanation I am assuming you are using Cucumber-JVM 4 and ISO8601 date formats. If you are using other date formats there are other resources to help you with that.

So lets say you have a step like this:

```
    Given an object with dates
      | localDate  | instant                  |
      | 2019-09-05 | 2015-06-02T21:34:33.616Z |
```

First define a step that accepts your object. Your object must be a POJO.

```
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class DateSteps {

    @Given("an object with dates")
    public void and_object_with_dates(Dates dates) {

    }

    public static class Dates {
        public LocalDate localDate;
        public Instant instant;

    }
}
```

Add a dependency on Jackson and JSR310 module to add support for the date time objects added by JSR310.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
```

Configure cucumbers type registry to use the object mapper with the JSR310 module enabled to convert data table cells, entries and parameter types.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JSR310Module;
import io.cucumber.core.api.TypeRegistry;
import io.cucumber.core.api.TypeRegistryConfigurer;
import io.cucumber.cucumberexpressions.ParameterByTypeTransformer;
import io.cucumber.datatable.TableCellByTypeTransformer;
import io.cucumber.datatable.TableEntryByTypeTransformer;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

import static java.util.Locale.ENGLISH;

public class ParameterTypes implements TypeRegistryConfigurer {

    @Override
    public Locale locale() {
        return ENGLISH;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureTypeRegistry(TypeRegistry typeRegistry) {
        Transformer transformer = new Transformer();
        typeRegistry.setDefaultDataTableCellTransformer(transformer);
        typeRegistry.setDefaultDataTableEntryTransformer(transformer);
        typeRegistry.setDefaultParameterTransformer(transformer);
    }

    private static class Transformer implements ParameterByTypeTransformer, TableEntryByTypeTransformer, TableCellByTypeTransformer {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JSR310Module());

        @Override
        public Object transform(String s, Type type) {
            return objectMapper.convertValue(s, objectMapper.constructType(type));
        }

        @Override
        public <T> T transform(Map<String, String> map, Class<T> aClass, TableCellByTypeTransformer tableCellByTypeTransformer) {
            return objectMapper.convertValue(map, aClass);
        }

        @Override
        public <T> T transform(String s, Class<T> aClass) {
            return objectMapper.convertValue(s, aClass);
        }
    }
}
```

You can now use JSR310 dates everywhere.

Comment: I was using an old version of cucumber. Updating it to jvm 4 and adding Jackson solved my issues :)